# Why expo start command not working without --tunnel?

Tags: react-native, expo

when I start app in local with expo start command it gives network error. But I can start with expo start --tunnel always. Why app does not start without --tunnel? I tried everything and searched other questions but did not resolve.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. Did you find a way to solve it?